# Coloring data in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, color, vector

I am trying to put color gradient on my data, or want values above some number to appear red and green below that number. For my situation the number is 5.14*10^(-13). I have X, Y, and Z axis data, respectively in the in the link. I tried using vectorcolorfunction and colordata and couldn't make it work.
This is my code

```
data = Import["DATA - Sheet1.csv"];
ve = Partition[data, 5];
vecdata = Partition[ve, 7]; 
v = ListVectorPlot3D[vecdata, DataRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}, {20, 30}}, 
  VectorPoints -> 5, VectorScale -> {0.1, Scaled[0.5]}]
```

[Link to my data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12LWcicApIFGZbYz7F1l95RwaV6NiSWE6zXluwxsXj-g/edit?usp=sharing)

My data produces this image

[image: This is how my data looks without color variation]

Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify which value x, y, or z you wish to consider, or some combination thereof.  Nevertheless this may help:

```
data = Import["DATA - Sheet1.csv"];
ve = Partition[data, 5];
vecdata = Partition[ve, 7]; 

ListVectorPlot3D[vecdata,
  DataRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}, {20, 30}},
  VectorPoints -> 5,
  VectorScale -> {0.1, Scaled[0.5]}, 
  VectorColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, If[Min[x, y, z] > 5.14*10^(-13), Red, Green]]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it